# Android - How to filter checkboxes with drawables by clicking a checkbox with multiple checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, drawable

I have been researching this, and I can't find a solution with a get drawable with a checkbox. What I'm trying to do is when you click this particular checkbox, it will filter the checkboxes of the corresponding color. This is in a fragment by the way. So, I have checkboxes that can be red, yellow, or green. If the user clicks on them, it changes the color. For example, I have a checkbox for the yellow which is chkProgress, and when it is clicked, I want to find all the checkboxes that are yellow and filter the checkboxes that are yellow. So, I have drawable ids, and I need to get the drawables to be able to locate the checkboxes that are that color. I want to be able to filter the checkboxes that are yellow when the user clicks chkProgress. So, here is my code:

```
private CheckBox [] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[2];

checkBoxes[0] = chkStart;
checkBoxes[1] = chkDownload;

private Drawable yellowDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_yellow_checkbox);

chkInProgess.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (chkInProgess.isChecked()){
                //something here
                if (chkStart.getDrawable == yellowDrawable) // need proper code here or a for loop to do this efficiently. 
            } else if (!chkInProgess.isChecked()){
                chkInProgess.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here are the checkboxes that I would need to find if they are yellow:

```
chkStart.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            countStart = checked(chkStart, countStart);
            editor.putInt(CHECK_START_ID, countStart);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });

chkDownload.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            countDownload = checked(chkDownload, countDownload);
            editor.putInt(CHECK_DOWNLOAD_ID, countDownload);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

Here is the method for checking the checkboxes if they are a certain color:

```
public int checked(CheckBox checkBox, int count){
    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
        count++;
    } else if (!checkBox.isChecked()){
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 1){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_yellow_checkbox);
    }
    if (count == 2){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_green_checkbox);
    }
    if (count > 2){
        count = 0;
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_red_checkbox);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here is the method when I resume the app:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    start = mSharedPreferences.getInt(CHECK_START_ID, 0);
    start = idChecked(chkStart, start);
    countStart = start;

    download = mSharedPreferences.getInt(CHECK_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
    download = idChecked(chkDownload, download);
    countDownload = download;
}
```

So, I am trying to get the drawables and match them to the checkboxes that are that color. I can't find anything that would help me. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have a state representation in a model?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. So, I made a method to check if the count of the checkbox was a certain number like I did for the checked method. I would set the checkbox with that number to visible or not.

```
public int colorCheckYellow(CheckBox checkbox, int value){
    if (value == 1)
        checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return value;
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
chkInProgess.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (chkInProgess.isChecked()) {
                 countStart = colorCheckYellow(chkStart, countStart);
                 countDownload = colorCheckYellow(chkDownload, countDownload);
            }else if (!chkInProgess.isChecked()) {
                 checkboxVisible();
            }
   }
```

I have some other code as well to make everything work but that was it!